# Regularised linear regression with Newton's method?

Tags: regression, optimization, ridge-regression

I am trying to use the Newton's method

$\theta^{(t+1)} = \theta^{(t)} - [H^{(t)}]^{-1} [\nabla L(\theta^{(t)})]$ to minimise the following loss fucntion

$L(\theta) =  (y - X\theta)^T(y-X\theta) + \lambda \theta^T\theta$

Here $\theta $ is $n\times 1$ vector, $X $ is $m\times n$ matrix,  $y $ is $m\times 1$ vector and $H^t = \nabla^2 L(\theta^{(t)})$ is the $n\times n$ Hessian matrix

I calculated the following details:

$\nabla L(\theta^{(t)}) = X^TX\theta^{(t)} + \lambda \theta^{(t)} - X^T y $ and

$H^t = X^TX + \lambda I_n$

Since, I know that there is a closed form solution to the loss function I am trying to minimise, I want to apply Newton's method by hand to this loss function and get that closed form again...
But in doing so, I am facing problem. The major problem is calculating the inverse of $X^TX + \lambda I_n$

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you really need to calculate the inverse for the purpose.
Substitute $\nabla L$ to the update function, you get

$$
\begin{align}
\theta^{(t+1)} &= \theta^{(t)} - H^{-1} \left[ (X^t X + \lambda I_n) \theta^{(t)} - X^ty\right] \\
&= \theta^{(t)} - H^{-1} H \theta^{(t)} + H^{-1} X^ty \\
&= H^{-1} X^ty
\end{align}
$$
This is the closed form solution to the linear ridge regression.
This means that the Newton's method converges in one step.

Comment: Indeed, the loss function is a quadratic and Newton's method has quadratic termination. +1